# How can I query multiple fields of an object array?

Tags: jq, aws-cli

I am querying AWS CLI output as per the json below.

```
{
"Aliases": [
    {
      "AliasName": "alias/ab1",
      "AliasArn": "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:123:alias/key1",
      "TargetKeyId": "66"
    },
    {
      "AliasName": "alias/ab2",
      "AliasArn": "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:123:alias/key2",
      "TargetKeyId": "77"
    },
    {
      "AliasName": "alias/ab3",
      "AliasArn": "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:123:alias/key3",
      "TargetKeyId": "88"
    },
    {
      "AliasName": "alias/ab4",
      "AliasArn": "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:123:alias/aws/key4",
      "TargetKeyId": "99"
    }
  ]
}
```

With query

```
.Aliases[] | (.AliasArn | select(contains(":alias/aws/") | not) )
```

But this only pulls `AliasArn` field, `TargetKeyId` is also required. Any ideas on how to pull both fields?

```
"arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:123:alias/key1"
"arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:123:alias/key2"
"arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:123:alias/key3"
```

Answer (score 1):

String Interpolation will work for this.

I'm called the AWS CLI `list-aliases` directly and piped it into `jq`, used the select/contains filter and piped it out using String Interpolation for output.

```
aws kms list-aliases |jq -r '.Aliases[] |select (.AliasArn |contains(":alias/aws/") | not) | "AliasArn: \(.AliasArn)\t\tTargetKeyId: \(.TargetKeyId)"'
```

I added a couple of tabs in the output for readability.

**References**

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: @sweeny_here if this A'er helped you get your issue resolved can you please mark it as accepted so everyone know's your issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kenlukas, that hit the nail on the head.

I made a small refinement to just capture the alias description along with the key as seen here -

```
aws kms list-aliases |jq -r '.Aliases[] |select (.AliasArn |contains(":alias/aws/") | not) | "AliasArn: \(.AliasArn | split("/")[1])\t\tTargetKeyId: \(.TargetKe yId)"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to the solution. You just need to add the field you want to get on your filter:

```
.Aliases[]|select(.AliasArn|contains(":alias/aws")|not) |.AliasArn,.TargetKeyId
```